# pycharm clone repository error, Repository test has failed

Tags: git, repository, pycharm

[image]

[image]

I don't know Why It happened..

Help me

Comment: Please put the informations in your question as text (not as a link to an image).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is `fatal: '/testing.git' does not appear to be a git repository`. This means that it was able to connect to the server and log in, but that it couldn't find the `/testing.git` directory, or that the directory exists but doesn't look like a git repository. Since `/testing.git` is an absolute path indicating a directory inside the root, try removing the `/` to see if the directory is actually inside the home directory instead.